# Skeleton Tracking on Raspberry Pi using Kinect

Tags: raspberry-pi, kinect, openni, openkinect, nite

I'm trying to do some skeleton tracking on Raspberry Pi.
I installed libfreenect and OpenNI. I can't find NITE ARM binaries anywhere as it is acquired by Apple and no support is provided now. Where can I find the other required binaries and how to install them on Raspberry Pi?